# Change the search icon in the action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've changed search icon on the Action Bar. And my search icon change to:

[image]

But I want change this search icon too:

[image]

How can i do it?

Comment: The top half is what you changed it to, and when you enter the `EditText` screen you still have the magnifying glass?  So you want to change the icon in there as well?

Comment: @Jay Snayder yes i want to change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your theme file

```
<style name="Theme" parent="Your parent theme">
 <item name="android:searchViewSearchIcon">@android:drawable/ic_search</item>
</style>
```

Comment: in eclipse work, but on phone doesn't. why?have another way to do that?

Comment: try dropping the android: from the item name.